# creating an if statement at login?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

hi im trying to find a way of adding an if-statement to my login script so that it checks my database to see if the column 'close_accounut' = '1' then to display this error message.

```
} else {
                    $closed_set = closed_account();
while ($closed = mysql_fetch_array($closed_set)) 
            if ($closed['close_account'] == '1')  {
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\">This account is closed. You recently closed your account. To regain access please email <a href=\"mailto:support@playtimeboys.com\">Support@PlaytimeBoys.com</a> session has expired.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close2\"></div></a>";
```

otherwise if close_account = '0' then display normal error message;

```
// email/password combo was not found in the database
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\"><strong>Email / Password combination incorrect.</strong><br />
                    Please make sure your caps lock key is off and try again.</div>";
                    echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close2\"></div></a>";
```

i have tried the following but this just does nothing, please can someone show me where i'm going wrong thanks

```
<?php

    if (logged_in()) 

{ 
$_SESSION['login_message']="<div class=\"login-overlay\"></div><div class=\"login-box\"><div class=\"loginframe2\">
<h1>Login You In Securely </h1>
<p>login you in securely. Please wait.<br/><br/>
<div class=\"login-logo\">
  <img src=\"assets/css/photobox/loading.gif\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"><div class=\"login-text-logo\">Login You In. Please Wait</div></div>
</div></div>"; 
header("Location:home.php");


}

    include_once("includes/form_functions.php");


    // START FORM PROCESSING
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
        $errors = array();

        // perform validations on the form data
        $required_fields = array('email', 'password');
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields, $_POST));

        $fields_with_lengths = array('email' => 50, 'password' => 30);
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_max_field_lengths($fields_with_lengths, $_POST));

        $email = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['email']));
        $password = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));
        $hashed_password = md5($password);


        if ( empty($errors) ) {
            // Check database to see if email and the hashed password exist there.
            $query = "SELECT id, email, close_account ";
            $query .= "FROM ptb_users ";
            $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
            $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
            $query .= "AND close_account = '0' ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_set = mysql_query($query);
            confirm_query($result_set);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {
                // email/password authenticated
                // and only 1 match
                $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $found_user['email'];
                $_SESSION['sub_expires'] = $found_user['subscription_expires'];





                $result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Online' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
or die(mysql_error());

if($result) 
{ 
$_SESSION['login_message']="<div class=\"login-overlay\"></div><div class=\"login-box\"><div class=\"loginframe2\">
<h1>Login You In Securely </h1>
<p> PlaytimeBoys.com is login you in securely. Please wait.<br/><br/>
<div class=\"login-logo\">
  <img src=\"assets/css/photobox/loading.gif\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"><div class=\"login-text-logo\">Login You In. Please Wait</div></div>
</div></div>"; 
header("Location:home.php");

}


            }else{

                // email/password combo was not found in the database
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\"><strong>Email / Password combination incorrect.</strong><br />
                    Please make sure your caps lock key is off and try again.</div>";
                    echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close2\"></div></a>";

            }

                } else {
                    $closed_set = closed_account();
while ($closed = mysql_fetch_array($closed_set)) 
            if ($closed['close_account'] == '1')  {
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\">This account is closed. You recently closed your account. To regain access please email <a href=\"mailto:support@playtimeboys.com\">Support@PlaytimeBoys.com</a> session has expired.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close2\"></div></a>";
```

Comment: With this indentation mess it's hard to see, but it looks like your blocks aren't scoped correctly (ie, the sequence of `{` and `}` that surround blocks isn't probably what you want).  I would suggest you clean up your code first, and check whether your code follows a `if (...) { .. } else { .. }` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed one '{' for while. Change your as bellow :

```
} else {
                    $closed_set = closed_account();
while ($closed = mysql_fetch_array($closed_set)) 
{
            if ($closed['close_account'] == '1')  {
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\">This account is closed. You recently closed your account. To regain access please email <a href=\"mailto:support@playtimeboys.com\">Support@PlaytimeBoys.com</a> session has expired.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close2\"></div></a>";
```